# The selector of the directive "TrimInputDirective" should have one of the prefixes - Angular Directive Linting Issue

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have written a directive that targets HTML inputs using CSS input selectors like so (I have shortened the code for ease of reading):

```
const TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrimInputDirective),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: `
    input
    :not([type=checkbox])
    :not([type=radio])
    :not([type=password])
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [formControlName],
  `,
  providers: [ TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class TrimInputDirective extends DefaultValueAccessor {
 // do stuff...
}
```

This all works as I expect however I have noticed that my linting gives me the following error:

> ERROR: app/shared/directives/trim-input.directive.ts[18, 13]: The
>   selector of the directive "TrimInputDirective" should have one of the
>   prefixes "myapp, if, file, use"
>   (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-08)

Now I can't do this as my selector isn't a defined attribute I would add to a HTML element. How can I resolve this error without wrapping my code in `/* tslint:disable */` and `/* tslint:enable */` comment flags?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to deal with this depending on desired outcomes.

If you want to disable this type of check across the board, you can update your `tslint.json` file. There are two properties of interest: `directive-selector": false`, `"component-selector": false`. Obviously you could turn one or the other off if you are just interested in stopping the linting errors for directives or components.

Alternatively, those properties can take a list of values, so you could update them to something as follows:

```
"directive-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "myapp"
]
```

If there are only a few places where you will be doing this, you can also use `/* tslint:disable-next-line */` in your code so you don't have to disable and then reenable linting. It will only ignore the line following that comment.